# Functions with rank $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> An open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ contains the closed origin-centered unit ball $B=B(0,1)$. If a $C^1$ mapping $f:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ with rank $n$ obeys $\|f(x)-x\|<1/2$ for all $x\in U$, show that,
>
> a) $\|f\|^2$ must attain a minimum in the interior of $B$.
>
> b) $f(p)=0$ for some $p\in B$.

Honestly I don't know how to solve such problems. I am planning to take an exam in few weeks which contains such problems. So I want to learn how to solve this. So I appreciate if someone would help me.

First of all what can be inferred from the fact that $f$ is of rank $n$? Does it imply that $f'$ is invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints to get you started:** What can you get from the condition $\|f(x)-x\|\le\frac12$ when $x=0$? When $\|x\|=1$? Also, consider the derivative of $\|f\|^2$ at a minimum point.

And for the last question: Yes, it implies that $f'(x)$ is invertible for every $x$.

Comment: By letting $g(x)=\|f(x)\|^2$, how can I define the derivative of $g$? Is it $2\|f\| Df$?

Comment: No, $g$ is a scalar function, so its derivative should be a vector (i.e., the gradient), not a matrix. Write $g=\sum_{k=1}^n f_k^2$, where $f=(f_1,\ldots,f_n)$ and then take partial derivatives. Express the result as a vector; you should get a product of $Df$ and a vector. (Or just take partial derivatives of the scalar product $f\cdot f$ directly, if the resulting algebra doesn't intimidate you.)

Comment: Ok I got $Dg=2Df^T(f_1,f_2,...,f_n)$. Now at the minimum, does $Dg=0$? Then how can I proceed to find the $x$ values at which $Dg=0$?

Comment: If $Dg=0$ then $\|Dg\|=0$. That is $2|Df^T|\|f\|=0$. Since $f'$ is invertible $\|f\|=0$. By the given inequality, when $\|f\|=0$, $\|x\|<1/2$. so I am done for part a). Am I correct?

Comment: You have the right idea, but taking norms/absolute value isn1t right, for the norm of a matrix product (or a matrix-vector product) is usually not the product of the norms. Instead, go back to $Dg=0$ (yes, that must hold at a minimum) and notice that the invertibility of $Df$ implies $f=0$ at the minimum. And then you're done.

Comment: Wait, I forgot a subtle point. You must rule out the minimum being on the boundary of the ball. At a minimum on the boundary, you can't know that $Dg=0$. But considering the value of $\|f(0)\|$ shows that this case cannot happen.